# :active and :hover both active at the same time, padding stacks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an issue with one of my designs at the moment, i'm creating a hover button using the :hover CSS element and then ensuring that it stays the same using the :active element.

However, both the :hover and :active have padding specified in their respective CSS rules which creates an issue when you click on the button whilst still hovering over it - the padding stacks and the button is completely misplaced.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Those are pseudo-classes, not elements. HTML has elements, CSS does not.

Comment: Define a rule for `:hover:active` that sets the `padding` to the preferred length/size.

Comment: The way the cascade works makes it impossible for two rules, setting padding on the same element, to be combined. The last rule in the cascade will override the previous one. I can think of a few possible situations where you might get that effect, but you would need to show  a complete reduced test case in order to determine which (if any) of those is the case.

Comment: @Quentin: now you mention it, yes. That never occurred to me, *sigh*. The choice, now, is *clearly*: 'caffeine' or 'sleep.'

Comment: Cant really help you without your html/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean (click the div to see hover/active).

HTML:

```
<div class="a">Some content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
}
.a:hover{
    padding:5px;
    background:red;
}
.a:active{
    padding:5px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/JsWCF/

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but it's a very clear illustration that the OP's premise indeed does not happen. Well done.

Comment: Since posting i've fixed the error, accepting this as the answer since it clearly shows I messed up somewhere else.